# Error 1067: "Windows could not start the SQL Server service on your Local computer" while attempting to start SQL Server service

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to start the **SQL Server service** on my computer.

The service was working fine when I had windows 10 with SQL Server 2017 but after upgrading my computer to windows 11, the service is not getting started. I also tried **reinstalling the SQL Server 2017**.

Later I **uninstalled** SQL Server 2017 and **installed SQL Server 2019** but still, I am not able to start the service and due to this, I am not able to connect my Management Studio with my database.

The error that I am getting in Event Viewer is:

```
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqllang.dll
```

I have also checked in the "**Local System Account**" in Log On tab of the SQL Server service.

I have tried reinstalling SQL Server 2017, uninstalling SQL Server 2017 and then installing SQL Server 2019, creating new server with another name, etc. but the neither the service is getting started nor my SSMS is connecting to the database.

Thanks

Comment: Consult the Event Viewer; what are the errors there? Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Hi.. I uploaded the images for clear understanding of my issue.

Comment: Images (of errors) *don't* help clarity; they do the opposite

Comment: Ohh. Thanks @Larnu for pointing out this. I will try not to upload images next time onwards. 
I opened the Event Viewer, there I am getting this -  "Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2019.150.2095.3, time stamp: 0x626c9e72
Faulting module name: sqllang.dll, version: 2019.150.2095.3, time stamp: 0x626c9f01
Exception code: 0xc0000005

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put it in the comments; though there will be more than "faulting application". And not "onwards", you need to address this question as well.

Comment: Check the error log, likely:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\<instance/version>\MSSQL\Log\ERRORLog
Change the credentials to your own (assuming your have admin on the box).
SQL Agent will never start until SQL Server is running, that is an expected state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a new *instance* of the SQL Server in another drive and now the service has started running.

**Note: Only the service for the new instance of the SQL Server *(installed in Disk D)* is running. The service for the previous instance that was installed in *Disk C* is *not running*.**

Answer (score 2):

After hours of fighting with this error, I finally ended up with this amazing solution of @rgv

I found a solution thanks to DATEV and their MS contact. It worked for my, try it at your own risk.

This is what helped me:

Go to start enter cmd.exe in the search field and run as admin.

Then enter the following line:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\stornvme\Parameters\Device" /v "ForcedPhysicalSectorSizeInBytes" /t reg_multi_sz /d "* 4095" /f
```

This registry key will force the sector size to 4095. Reboot your PC, go back to the command promt and enter this time:

```
fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo c:
```

This should now return 4096 as in the below.

```
C:\Windows\System32>fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo c:
LogicalBytesPerSector :                                 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity :                    4096
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance :                  4096
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096
Device Alignment :                                      Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device :                         Aligned (0x000)
No Seek Penalty
Trim Supported
Not DAX capable
Not Thinly-Provisioned
```

Afterwards I was able to install the SQL server without any issues. So far the feedback I received is that mostly Samsung SSD drives with 1TB or rather 980 GB are affected, I hope they'll roll out an official fix soon, but as I said this worked for me. Good luck! And thank you all for your feedback and help!!!